# PhalconPHP - Cannot load controllers if they are namespaced with Loader

Tags: php, phalcon

Before I namespaced my application (test app), everything worked fine.
But after I started namespacing the controllers, and everything and loading the namespaces like this:

```
    $loader = new Loader();
    $loader->registerNamespaces(
        array(
            'Application\Controllers' => 'Application/Controllers/'
        )
    )->register();
```

I get the error `Exception: IndexController handler class cannot be loaded`

My namespace I entered is correct:

```
namespace Application\Controllers;

use Phalcon\Mvc\Controller;

class IndexController extends Controller {

    public function indexAction() {
        echo "Hello World";
    }
}
```

[image: img]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](http://gyazo.com/c7895dbf51b37d6410c0dc8f5ec2cbb2.png))</sub>

I managed to fix it by adding a default namespace to the Router:

```
$router = new Router();
$router->setDefaultNamespace('Application\Controllers');
```

But that might cause me further problems, because namespace loader doesn't seem to work.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nothing is wrong, the namespace registration both in the Loader and Router are required steps.

At first instance you configured only your loader. So if you test somewhere:

`$controller = new Application\Controllers\IndexController();`
It will work.

However you didn't tell yet to your router that all your routes should point to the `Application\Controllers` namespace. So it attempts to find the `\IndexController` class which is indeed non existent.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just have to set the root of the namespace and then the Loader will do the scaffolding:

```
$loader = new Loader();
$loader->registerNamespaces(
    array(
        'Application' => 'Application'
    )
)->register();
```

And are you sure that you are getting the Application folder correct? try:

```
$loader = new Loader();
$loader->registerNamespaces(
    array(
        'Application' => '~/Application/'
    )
)->register();
```

Comment: Yes the folder is correct because it works if I remove the namespaces from the controller.